# If Function for Multiple Values

Tags: excel

I am looking for a way to tell Excel to count a certain number of disjoint cells if the value of each cell is equal to a or else equal to b.  Is there a simple way to do this without setting up a nested if statement for each individual cell?  Thanks!

Comment: no, you have to put the nested logic.

Comment: I think it truly depends on your definition of "disjoint cells", but it might be possible with either a `Sumifs` function or `SumProduct`.

Comment: Rather a COUNTIFS statement would probably be best since he wants a count. But in 99% of cases like this there's no need for nested logic in any version of Excel since '07 when they came out with *IFS formulas. But yes, it rests on your definitions of "disjoint"

Comment: I'm not sure about the disjointed cells part, but to see if a cell value is one of two given values, say 20 and 5, I'd use something like =OR((A1=20,A1=5)). To get a numeric value out of that, add *1 to the end. That'd give you a bunch of values you can add up to get the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following disjoint (i.e., not contiguous) data in columns `C:E`, and suppose we want to test whether each value `=20` or `=5`:

```
+---+---+--+----+---+----+
|   | A | B| C  | D | E  |
+---+---+--+----+---+----+
| 1 | 0 |  | 10 |   |    |
| 2 | 1 |  |    |   | 20 |
| 3 | 1 |  |    |   |    |
| 4 |   |  |    | 5 |    |
| 5 |   |  |    |   |    |
| 6 | 2 |  |    |   |    |
+---+---+--+----+---+----+
```

The formula in `A1` is `=(--(C1=20)+--(C1=5))`. Deconstructing this, `(C1=20)` returns a boolean `True` or `False`.

The `--` prefix is a [well known Excel trick](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel%20double%20unary%20minus&oq=excel%20double%20unary%20minus&aqs=chrome..69i57.699j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) that coerces the boolean value to an integer `0 (False)` or `1 (True)`.

Adding these two coerced booleans has the same effect as a logical `OR` statement*.

In summary this formula is equivalent to `C1=20 OR C1=5`. Since `C1=20` is `False (0)` and `C1=5` is `False (0)`, the result is `0`.

The formulae in `A2` and `A3` are similarly constructed, but pointed to columns `E` and `D`.

Finally we pull it all together in cell `A6` with

```
=(--(C1=20)+--(C1=5)+--(E2=20)+--(E2=5)+--(D4=20)+--(D4=5))
```

...which looks pretty tedious (and it is). Nevertheless I recommend you experiment with the idea that `IF` functions, and in particular nested `IF` functions, can be reworked using boolean logic in this manner. Sometimes, at least, the formula is easier to write and the intent is easier to read.

*P.S. multiplication is equivalent to logical `AND`.

PPS: I amend my answer to say the "double unary minus" trick is well known in some circles, but it is so useful it should be part of every user's Excel lexicon.